# Not able to build and deploy Mobilefirst app on Iphone

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, mobilefirst-studio

My environment setup is:
Eclipse luna
Mobilefirst version 7.1.0.00-20151012-1525
OS windows 7

I am working on a app in which I have added IPhone environment and to deploy app on IPhone copied native folder to mac and using xcode to deploy but having following error.

> /Users/sanketkulkarni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoDemoIphone-azvbaszihidylngstqhkzbapopkq/Build/Intermediates/DemoDemoIphone.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoDemoIphone.build/Script-427B829D1393724500F223DC.sh: /Projects/sanket/06-04-2016/native/buildtime.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the app is not actually built.

Make sure you have first select Run As -> Run on MobileFirst Development Server, and then copy the iphone\native folder.

Note though that it would be better if you will do your development on your Mac to begin with.

Is there a reason why you are developing on Windows/Linux, and then moving your code to Mac?

Comment: Actually I was building all env Run As -> Build All Environments isn't it enough to take native folder to Mac.

Comment: I would use the option I mentioned.

Comment: I tried that option too but no change. now trying to add environment from a Mac, I think that will work but also need to check if I pushed that code to gerrit and pulled from another mac that works or not.

Comment: I am using same .gitignore file given in IBM documents for MF 7.1

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar  while doing run as Xcode project am getting this error : Failed Running Xcode. Cannot locate xcodeproj folder in /Users/xx/xx/xx/apps/xxx/iphone/native

but if i open that folder i can see the xcode project .

i removed the native folder but no change, am  using mac